# excel VLOOKUP multiple occurances

Tags: excel, vlookup, billing, invoice

I have 2 excel sheets, Bill and DB. 
The 'Bill sheet consists of 2 columns 'product name' & ' Tax %' and few more which are not relevant to the question. 
The DB sheets has 'prod name' and ' Tax %' only.

Now I want to add a Drop-Down option in Bill sheet for 'product name' which on selecting will directly give me the respective tax % to that product name.

I am doing it using VLOOKUP func.
problem-- when I select the product name in this order-

---

( prod name    |       tax % )-----
          (  x        |         4)
          ( z         |        10)
          (x          |        blank[ #N/A already resolved])
          (y          |        blank[ #N/A already resolved])
          (y          |        blank[ #N/A already resolved])

---

and so on.....

I want to get same product name more than 1 number of time in a single bill.
Need some help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell based on the limited description of this problem, but what you could be running into is your VLOOKUP formula needs to have an absolute cell reference for the lookup range. You can add $ in front of each Column Letter and Cell number to lock the range in place, or hitting F4 will cycle through the different absolute reference options.

Comment: Wyatt Shipman, If you could go to this Link and watch it between 9:10 to 12:00(approx). You can see that he has illustrated 1 loop of pname1, pname2, pname3 on the Invoice sheet from the drop-down. but what if I need it like pname1,pname2,pname3, pname2, pname1 .. I am not getting values displayed for the last 2 entries.

Comment: Aww. Missed the Important part.Sorry. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32bdv3VzirM

Comment: After selecting the table array in the first formula, press the F4 key. In his example, the table array should look like `products2!$A$2:$B$4` and it will lock down the lookup range. What is happening is that when he drags the VLOOKUP formula down, the table array range is moving down equally so that by the 4th cell, the table array is referencing A5:B7.